# Insert new dates with dynamic formula to include new range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Raw Data]

I need to insert new dates as I add new dates I need to calculate the 4 wk, 8 wk, & 13 wk. For example, if I inserted 2/10/2024, I would need the formula to take into account the new date and provide the 4 wk, 8 wk, & 13 wk average.

I used this formula:

```
=ROUND(AVERAGE(OFFSET(D4, 0, COUNTA(D3:P3)-4, 1, 4))*4.33, 0)
```

But, when I inserted a new date into the column, the formula would not take into account the new date. Every month I'll be adding new dates and I need to formula to work dynamically.